# Rails failed to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk Gem File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy the ruby application to elastic beanstalk and I am having an error as follows;

```
   Creating application version archive "app-bf30-181005_152130".
    Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
    2018-10-05 12:22:41    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
    2018-10-05 12:23:27    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
    2018-10-05 12:23:42    ERROR   [Instance: i-04907e391d0f1504d] Command failed on instance. Return code: 5 Output: (TRUNCATED)... depends on
                rAn error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
  Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.

  In Gemfile:
    dropzonejs-rails was resolved to 0.7.3, which depends on
      rails was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
        actionmailer was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
          actionpack was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
            actionview was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
              rails-dom-testing was resolved to 1.0.7, which depends on
                rails-deprecated_sanitizer was resolved to 1.0.3, which depends on
                  activesupport was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
                    json (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError) 
    Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
    2018-10-05 12:23:42    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
    2018-10-05 12:23:42    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-04907e391d0f1504d'. Aborting the operation.
    2018-10-05 12:23:43    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.        

    ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.
```

Is it because of the versioning? I could not find a solution. The ruby version of elastic beanstalk is shown as 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nop, it's the json gem that cannot be installed.

Try updating your rubygems locally, then you Gemfile.

Then retry deploying (should be 'eb deploy' with was toolbelt)

If still doesn't work, please provide here the content of /var/log/eb-activity.log like the error states.